# Beginning Android 4 Games Development error

Tags: java, android

In the book Beginning Android 4 games development by Mario Zechner and Robert Green I am following along to start making a game of my own. We create a framework for the game first and then implement it into one class, and I got one error which I could not figure out. The error occured when I tried to instantiate something from a class called AndroidFileIO.

This is how the book describes how to instantiate it:

```
FileIO fileIO

fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
```

and the class it gets it from is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import com.example.android4gamedevtut.FileIO;

public class AndroidFileIO implements FileIO{

    Context context;
     AssetManager assets;
     String externalStoragePath;

     public AndroidFileIO(Context assetManager) {
     this.context = assetManager;
     this.assets = assetManager.getAssets();
     this.externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
     }



    @Override
     public InputStream readAsset(String fileName) throws IOException {
     return assets.open(fileName);
     }
     @Override
     public InputStream readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
     return new FileInputStream(externalStoragePath + fileName);
     } 

     @Override
     public OutputStream writeFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
     return new FileOutputStream(externalStoragePath + fileName);
     }

     public SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
     return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     } 
}
```

The error that is stopping me is saying "The constructor AndroidFileIO(AssetManager) is undefined" and eclipses suggests too fixes to the problem. The first being to "change the constructor AndroidFileIO(Context) to AndroidFileIO(AssetManager)" and the second being "create a constructor AndroidFileIO(AssetManager)". Please answer this question in simple terms I am very new to java.

Comment: The constructor expects a `Context` object, but you are giving it an `AssetManager` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
    fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
```

instead of getAsset();

refer to line 54 in https://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games-2/source/browse/trunk/ch09-jumper/src/com/badlogic/androidgames/framework/impl/GLGame.java?r=4